# Check programmatically in Android if at least one account has been setup

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have been trying to determine if any account has been setup or not in Android device.

I have tried the following code but it returns empty list. Is there any way to find  out if accounts have been setup in Android or not?

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(applicationContext);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts()
```

I have setup the required permission in the android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your API level is 23 (or above) , I think you'll need to ask for the permission at runtime, try this:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission. GET_ACCOUNTS) == getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
  // permission granted, get the accounts here
  accountManager = AccountManager.get(applicationContext);
  Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts()

}
else
{
  // permission not granted, ask for it:

  // if user needs explanation , explain that you need this permission (I used an alert dialog here)
  if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Permission Needed")
    .setMessage("App needs permission to read your accounts ... etc")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION);
      }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    })
    .create().show();
  }

  // no explanation needed, request the permission
  else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION);
  }

}
```

And then Override this method, to handle users response

```
// this function is triggered whenever the application is asked for permission and the user made a choice
// it check user's response and do what's needed.
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
  if (requestCode == GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION) {

    // check if user granted or denied the permission:
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
      // permission was granted , do the work related to account here:
      accountManager = AccountManager.get(applicationContext);
      Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts()
    }

    else
    {
      //permission denied, what do you want to do?
    }
  }
}
```

and you need to define `GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION` in the class (not inside methods), it's a constant so you know which permission is requested, you can replace it with whatever name or value you want .
also define accountManager so it can be accessible from both methods.

```
int GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION = 0;
AccountManager accountManager;
```